# Create a {dynamic_type} mapping in Elasticsearch with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I'm trying to translate some JSON-based Elasticsearch index definitions from elasticsearch-net 1.x to elasticsearch-net 5.4 with the NEST library. The original mappings contain a `"dynamic_template"` with a type of `"{dynamic_type}"`, but I cannot determine how to recreate this with the current NEST library.

There are some legacy [Github issues](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1318) and documentation pointing to being able to set an explicit `Type()` on a mapping using a string value of `"{dynamic_type}"`, but those methods do not exist in the current version of the library.

Here's our original index definition:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 2,
        "number_of_replicas": 2
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [{
                    "default_template": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "doc_values": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "timestamp": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I've managed to recreate almost the same mapping using NEST, but for setting the mapping type.

```
_client.CreateIndex("test_index", desc => desc
    .Settings(settings => settings
        .NumberOfShards(2)
        .NumberOfReplicas(2))
    .Mappings(mappings => mappings
        .Map<object>("_default_", s => s
            .AllField(all => all
                .Enabled(false))
            .DynamicTemplates(dynamicTemplates => dynamicTemplates
                .DynamicTemplate("default_template", defaultTemplate => defaultTemplate
                    .Match("*")
                    .Mapping(mapping => mapping
                        .Generic(g => g
                            .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                            .DocValues(true)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Properties(properties => properties
                .Date(date => date.Name("timestamp"))
            )
        )
    ));
```

The above create statement results in this index definition:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 2,
    "index.number_of_shards": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "default_template": {
            "match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, am I missing something? Is `{dynamic_type}` even necessary?

I wasn't sure about the usage of `SingleMappingDescriptor.Generic()`, but it seemed close to what I'm after. The NEST library desperately needs documentation.

Comment: `{dynamic_type}` is necessary; looks like it's missing currently - would you mind opening an issue for it? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues

Comment: Opened https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/2817